# Value based on interval belonging

Tags: python

Is there any more pythonic way of calculating value based on interval belonging?
I'm looking for more elegant form of this function:

```
def c(x):
    if x < -.3:
        return -1
    if x < .3:
        return 0
    return 1
```

Comment: Do you want to pass many values such as array, to the function?

Comment: Nope, only floats